# pip install fails with "no such option: --no-deps"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to install my own Python package into a Python2.7 virtual environment on Windows, but I get

```
    Installed c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine
    Error: no such option: --no-deps

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine\.env2\scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\niklas\\repos\\ppy\\engine\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps" failed with error code 2 in C:\Users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine\
```

This does not happen when I do a normal installation (no `-e` flag). I've been checking the Pip and setuptools release notes, but it says nowhere the that a `--no-deps` option was removed.

I also added a print to my `setup.py` before `setup()` is called to print `sys.argv` which gives me

```
['-c', 'develop', '--no-deps']
```

so it must be `setup()` that is complaining. I also don't get this error when installing into a Python 3.5 virtual environment.

- pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine.env2\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
- setuptools 34.3.1

---

*Edit*: As it turns out, the normal installation also doesn't work but then it's the `--record` flag that is not recognized.

```
    Installing node.py-script.py script to c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine\.env2\Scripts
    Installing node.py.exe script to c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine\.env2\Scripts
    Installing node.py.exe.manifest script to c:\users\niklas\repos\ppy\engine\.env2\Scripts
    writing list of installed files to 'c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\pip-okk7gy-record\install-record.txt'
    Error: no such option: --record
```

Comment: Show which command did you use for install your package and all flags.

Comment: @Budulianin `pip install . --upgrade -v` for normal install (also doesn't work, I missed the `--upgrade` flag before and thus it actually skipped the installation) and `pip install -e . --upgrade -v` for a develop install. I also tried `pip uninstall node.py` first and then using one of the two install commands above, to no avail.

Comment: I also just tried to replace `setuptools.setup()` with `distutils.core.setup()` in my `setup.py` but it gives the same errors.

Comment: does it work with pip <9?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't want to necro this thread but after I have seen many suggestions this worked for me:

installation dir => `python.exe -m pip install -U pip`